# ldap. What is binddn_passwd

Tags: nginx, ldap

I installed Nginx with LDAP, it works. But I can't understand the purpose of "binddn" and "binddn_passwd"

```
ldap_server dc1 { 
url ldap://dc1.alexlinux.lan:3268/DC=alexlinux,DC=lan?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person); 
binddn "alexlinux\\comp"; 
binddn_passwd 123; 
group_attribute member; 
group_attribute_is_dn on; 
require valid_user; 
require group "CN=systemtest,OU=Groups,DC=alexlinux,DC=lan"; 
}
```

When I open browser, I inter my domain login and password.
Without these parameters authentication doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, there exist two approaches to use LDAP to authenticate.

- The first one tries to use the username and password you entered in the web browser to *bind* to the ldap server (this is LDAP speak meaning to login to the LDAP server). If the bind is successful, the username and password where correct and you are logged into your website. However, this requires that the LDAP server is configured to allow this kind of operation, which is not always the case.
- The second method works even if the first one isn't allowed. With this method, the LDAP client (`nginx` in your case), binds to the LDAP server as a user that is allowed to verify other users and then use the data supplied in the web browser to verify the user and report back. To do this, it needs to know which user (*Distinguished Name* or `DN` in LDAP speak) and which password is should use for this bind. They are configured in the parameters `binddn` and `binddn_passwd` in `nginx`.

Comment: Can you send the number of RFC and section? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this github [page](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap). It would seem that the 'binddn' is the username you login to the ldap server along with the binddn_passwd being the password.
Some bind servers require a login before they reveal information to a connection.

Answer (score -1):

Ldap server requires distinguished user name (something like cn=Test User,ou=something,dc=example,dc=org) to authenticate user. But in most cases users prefer to login just as "Test user". So, to obtain distinguished name of user record, client (nginx) should connect to ldap server and find record which user login attribute (sAMAccountName in your case) equals user name. If server allows for anonymous user to connect and do such search, binddn and binddn_password not required, but if server secured, you must provide credentials to do a search.

After user DN is obtained (if search query returned any results) client binds (authenticates) on ldap server with user DN and user password. If succeeded - user authenticated.